# OS X El Capitan installation error: AMD-Action:authenticate:SP

Tags: macos, usb, install, apple-id

When doing a clean re-installation of El Capitan (highest supported version) from a bootable USB on an older Mac (MBP, 15-inch, Late 2008), I get this error:

> An unexpected error occured while signing in.
>
> AMD-Action:authenticate:SP

The error shows up, while logging in with the Apple ID into the App Store in the installer.

- I tried with different Apple IDs,
- Also tried running these commands
  in the Recovery Terminal and restarting:

  csrutil clear

  csrutil enable

Comment: Instead of, or in addition to, saying "_on an older Mac_", provide the exact hardware information of the model Mac you're working with.

Comment: Ok, added into the question

Answer (score 11):

The problem was that the old Mac did not have its date set correctly.

1. Hold `Option (ALT) + Command + R` at Mac startup to start internet recovery
2. Going into `Utilities > Terminal` starts the recovery terminal
3. **Run `date mmddHHMMyy` - this solves the problem (date must be in PST!)**
4. Run `csrutil enable`
5. Run `csrutil clear`
6. Exit the recovery terminal and continue OS X installation normally.

[Here is the full step-by-step solution](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7694323?start=0&tstart=0) to solve the problem.

Comment: Happened to me on an older MacBook which I didn't boot up in a while when trying to do an update. El Capitain was already installed though, so I didn't need to go into recovery mode. Correcting the time was enough.

Comment: Setting the time also worked for me.  Though had to use PDT due to the time of the year.

Comment: Just to add to Peter Gerhat's answer above (I don't have enough rep to comment on it directly): If you have two-factor auth enabled and you hit this message, change the date as instructed, exit recovery entirely, reboot again, then proceed as normal.

Comment: From Chris Chandler: "If you have two-factor auth enabled and you hit this message, change the date as instructed, exit recovery entirely, reboot again, then proceed as normal."

Answer (score 1):

For me, the problem was because I did not have access to the Shared folder under Users in the primary drive. When i changed permission for the Shared folder via 'Get Info>Folder permission>Set to read', the problem was resolved..

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely related to two factor authentication. I was getting this error message when trying to download MacOS High-Sierra from an El-Capitan installation. What fixed the problem for me was to first download something else from the app store. I as then asked to authenticate with tfa and subsequently was allowed to download macos.