# AMD-Action:downloadProduct:SP error on clean install

Tags: macos, imac, disk-utility, install, error

I'm getting the AMD-Action:downloadProduct:SP error when trying to reinstall macOS, it doesn't even get to the option to sign in with an apple ID.

I've tried the solutions below but it's still not working:

[OS X El Capitan installation error: AMD-Action:authenticate:SP](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/273983/os-x-el-capitan-installation-error-amd-actionauthenticatesp)

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7694323?answerId=30940143022#30940143022

I've also tried creating a bootable usb using transmac starting by making a GPT partition but it doesn't get discovered as a boot device.

iMac Late 2013

Comment: Can you add some details about how exactly the answers to the previous question failed to help you? Right now we don‘t have enough information to propose alternative approaches.

Comment: See the answer on the question shown in the yellow box on top. Apparently Apple's recommendation is to bring the computer into a service center.